# file descriptor number increases when using websocket and nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, websocket, file-descriptor

I am using Websocket library [ws npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws) at 5001 and nodejs for port 80 communication.

My issue is over a period of time number of File Descriptors increases which results into more RAM consumption.

Below is my code.

```html
var SOCKETS = [];

//Used for publish URL
var app = https.createServer(options, function(req, response){
   log.debug("connection:"+ req.url);
   var path = url.parse(req.url,true).pathname;
   log.debug('path:'+path);
   //response.writeHead(200,{ 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
   switch(path){
            case '/push':
                
                client.send(user_message);

                response.writeHead(200,{ 'Content-Type': 'text/json' });
                response.write(JSON.stringify({ 'userids': valid_users}));
                break;
   }
   // Send HTML headers and message
   response.end('');

});

app.listen(config.websocket_port);

var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server
  , wss = new WebSocketServer({ server: app } );

wss.on('connection', function(ws) {
    ws.on('message', function(userid) {
        ws.userid = userid;
        if(SOCKETS[userid]){
            delete SOCKETS[userid];
        }
        SOCKETS[userid] = ws;
        log.debug("Userid: " + userid.toString() + " connected");
    });

    ws.on('close', function(){
       log.debug(" Socket with userid closed ", ws.userid);
       var userid = ws.userid;
       if(SOCKETS[userid] == ws){
           SOCKETS[userid] = null;
       }
       delete SOCKETS[userid];
    });

    ws.on('error', function(){
        log.debug(" Socket error ");      
    });

});
```

Can someone help with this ?

Comment: What do you mean by FD? I guess the garbage collector should be handling this memory issue.

Comment: Sorry about that it is File Descriptors. No garbage collector is not freeing it up. Every few minutes count increases and over a period of 7 days it becomes 6000-10000.

Comment: You could create a pool of Http connections and start push your requests through them, or you could limit the max concurrent requests from your client and any requests exceeding this limit would be added to a queue so you can process them later.Or you could change the operational system file descriptor limit (`ulimit -n` in ubuntu)